# Error datos truncados, Mysql, tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter, mysqlconnector

estoy tratando de sacar los datos de varias entradas en tkinter y enviarlas a Mysql. Pero la terminal me arroja el siguiente error: **mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'N_guía' at row 1**
Hasta donde logro ver, no hay errores de sintaxis. El valor de la columna está declarado como "int", lo he intentado poniendo números con uno, dos y hasta siete dígitos pero nada funciona. Cualquier ayuda estaré agradecido.

```
  #Función guardar ticket
        def nuevo_ticket():
            conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
            cursor1=conn.cursor()
            cursor1.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vehículos (Placa text) ''')
            cursor1.execute("INSERT INTO Vehículos VALUES ('{0}')".format(self.entry_placa.get()))
            cursor1.execute('''INSERT INTO Ticket(Placa,
            Conductor, 
            Cedula, 
            Producto, 
            Proveedor, 
            Cliente, 
            Guia, 
            Peso, 
            Diferencia, 
            Transporte, 
            Fecha_hora, 
            N_guía, 
            Observaciones) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}', '{10}', '{11}', '{12}') '''.format(self.entry_placa.get(), 
            self.entry_conductor.get(), 
            self.entry_cedula_conductor.get(), 
            self.entry_producto.get(),
            self.entryprov.get(),
            self.entrycli.get(), 
            self.entry_peso_guia.get(),
            Variable_peso.get(),
            Variable_tara.get(),
            Variable_neto.get(),
            self.entry_transporte.get(),
            Variable_tiempo.get(),
            self.entry_num_guia.get(),
            self.entry_observaciones.get("1.0", "end-1c")))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
```

Comment: ¿No será un problema con el acento de la `í` de `N_guía`?  Prueba renombrando la columna sin el acento a ver si supera el error (quizas es un problema de codificación de la conexión al tener ese acento).

Comment: Lo intenté y no funcionó, gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Pues quizás deberías comprobar el valor que arroja `self.entry_num_guia.get()` para ver si es un integer o no.

Comment: Si lo es, es un entry de tkinter y solo acepta números (no he puesto todo el código porque es muy largo) y cómo mencioné en la pregunta lo intenté con valores de dos hasta siete dígitos. con todos pasa lo mismo.

Comment: ¿De qué longitud es `self.entry_num_guia.get()`? ¿De qué longitud es el campo? `N_guía`? ¿Probaste colocar acentos graves (_backticks_, ``) a cada columna?

Comment: self.entry_num_guia.get() es un custom tkinter entry, he usado números de uno hasta siete dígitos. La columna N_guía es "int" que soporta hasta nueve dígitos. Y no, no lo he probado. ¿Los pongo cuando se crea la tabla?

Comment: Ponlos en los nombres de columna que hay dentro de `Ticket()`... de todos modos, si omites la columna `N_guía` te funciona la inserción? Entiendo que si, solo queria saber si lo has probado para evitar errores posteriores.

Comment: Lo intentaré, gracias